# Tikz: Creating a rectangle with a fake \parbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

In the example below, I am trying to get identical blue and red boxes, without any text in the red one. I would like to have the red box exactly identical to the blue one, whose size depends on the content of the parbox, but without inserting any text in it? Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=red,inner sep=1cm]{\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\vphantom{Title}}};
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=blue,opacity=.5,inner sep=1cm]{\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{Title}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue not explained here in details is that I am using a blend mode of Tikz which affects the text:

```
\draw[anchor=north] (midpoint) node [fill=black!75!ocre,blend mode=color,text width=\paperwidth,inner sep=1cm]{\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\color{white} Text}};
```

and I want to keep the text as white. One solution is to add the text later in a different node.

Comment: You can use `fit` library to build a red box which exactly fits the blue one

Comment: Could you explain why do you want it? With this example, just a box with "correct" color would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for extra libraries nor big modification to your code; you're code will work as soon as TeX sees something in the `\parbox` such as a box of zero width (since the requirement in the question was to have "no text" in the box):

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=red,inner sep=1cm]{\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\mbox{}\vphantom{Title}}};
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=blue,opacity=.5,inner sep=1cm]{\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{Title}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **percusse** mentioned in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226879/tikz-creating-a-rectangle-with-a-fake-parbox/226902?noredirect=1#comment534244_226902) you could even dispense with the use of the `\parbox`es and give the desired width using `text width`:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=red,inner sep=1cm,text width=\paperwidth]{\vphantom{Title}};
\draw[anchor=north] (current page.north) node [fill=blue,opacity=.5,inner sep=1cm,text width=\paperwidth]{Title};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem with your original code is that the `\vphantom` gives you the necessary height but the `\parbox` will still be empty. Adding the `\mbox{}` allows to set the specified width.

Comment: Still why parbox instead of a node with inner sep?

Comment: @percusse why, indeed? I've updated my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @percusse but, then one might ask, why TikZ at all for doing this? :) Since the actual intent wasn't clear in the question, it's hard to tell which approach is the best one here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina with percusse's suggestion, I think you can delete `\mbox{}`, with `\vphantom` is enough. You need `\mbox` only with `\parbox`.

Comment: @Ignasi Yes, you're right. Box deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works. Sadly, I tried something similar with a misplaced `\mbox{}`. My problem being more complicated than the provided ECM, this is not really a solution.

Comment: Finally, well I think this will do trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `let` operation (needs `calc` library)

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=blue,inner sep=1cm,text width=0.5\paperwidth,anchor=north](a) at (0,0){Title};
\draw
 let \p1 = ($ (a.east) - (a.west) $),
     \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
     \p2 = ($ (a.south) - (a.north) $),
     \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
in
node [fill=red,inner sep=1cm,minimum width=\n1,minimum height=\n2,anchor=north,opacity=.5] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by Ignasi, you can use `fit` library too (easier)

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=blue,inner sep=1cm,text width=0.5\paperwidth](a) at (0,0){Title};
\node [fit=(a),fill=red,inner sep=2pt,opacity=0.5]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`inner sep=2pt,` in the red node is just for demonstration and make it `0pt` to fit exactly.

Comment: Interesting but not acceptable as you draw the red box after the blue one: I want the red one before the blue one, even though we know the size of the blue one only.

Comment: @pluton I don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: :) really too bad! Just get one.

Comment: @pluton: Really I don't know your aim. If you fix the width of blue box say at `\paperwidth` using `text width =\paperwidth`, then you can draw the red one before blue using the same `text width=\paperwidth`. Why do you want to use an explicit `\parbox`? It is not the `tikz` way, `text width =\paperwidth` is.

Comment: @pluton Only if you tell me from where ;-)

Comment: I edited my post to explain why I need this. This is related to the blend modes in Tikz and how text is "inappropriately" rendered with this option.